# How server checks if the request from client is still active to the flask api?

Tags: python, flask, sublimetext3, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a flask api that does some function process and takes little minutes to return. Some times request will be get aborted by the client. In these situations I would like to cancel processing. How can I do this in flask?

I have found a temporary solution.

```
@app.route('/stream')
    def stream():
       def gen():
           try:
               i = 0
               while True:
                   data = 'this is line {}'.format(i)
                   print(data)
                   yield data + '<br>'
                   i += 1
                   time.sleep(1)
           except GeneratorExit:
               print('closed')

return Response(stream_with_context(gen()))
```

Now this works for browser when we request through sublime and after some time we close the sublime the flask api is not recognising the client termination

Answer (score 0):

Use celery package, and run that function as task. Then you can use any other route to fire up the revoke() function, which stops celery task, eg. your_worker.revoke(task_id, terminate=True).

Comment: Can we use a multiprocessing function inside celery task.?

Comment: Celery IS about multiprocessing. You can add multiple tasks to each worker, and then start / stop them one by one, or all at once.